# cURL Docker registry authorization error "authentication required"

Tags: docker, curl, docker-registry, docker-repository

I have set up docker auth server using cesanta and used mongodb for ACL everything works fine. Only issue is when I am doging curl to my registry catalog I got UNAUTHORIZED.

```
curl -Lk https://example.docker.com:5000/v2/_catalog
```

I am getting below error:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication
required","detail":[{"Type":"registry","Class":"","Name":"catalog","Action":"*"}]}]}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to acquire a bearer token to be used as header for authentication. Here is a detail doc on how to get it https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/docs/spec/auth/token.md

Comment: Link is dead as of 2023-12-12

Comment: @AndrásAszódi you can try older branch  https://github.com/distribution/distribution/blob/docker/1.13/docs/spec/auth/token.md